# Is it possible to interact with the content elements in a not active tab with chrome extention?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I will try to ask my question as good as possible:

In Chrome browser, i have two tabs are working (one with google.com and the other with bing.com loaded) and the Google loaded tab is selected. The input element id of Google searchbox is "gbqfq" and the input element id of Bing's searchbox is "sb_form_q".

### My manifest.json file's content is as below:

```
{
  "name": "MyExtention",
  "version": "0.1.1",
  "description": "Description",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://*.bing.com/*","*://*.google.com/*"],
      "css": ["basic.css"],
      "js": ["jquery.js", "contentscript.js"]
    }
  ],
 "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'",
 "web_accessible_resources": ["*"] ,
 "permissions":["tabs","*://*.bing.com/*","*://*.google.com/*"],
 "externally_connectable": {
   "matches": ["*://*.bing.com/*","*://*.google.com/*"]
 },
 "background": {"scripts": ["background.js"] },
   "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

Is it possible to interact with the elements in all open tab's with chrome.extention?

My chrome.extention finds the element's by id either from "google.com" and "bing.com" when their tab's are selected (active) but can not pass the element value's from selected tab to not selected tab.

What i want to do is to get the value of an input element from one tab's content and change the value of an input element in another tab's content.

Is this possible with chrome.extentions?
If it is possible; how can i manage it?

**P.S  :**

> - I am not looking for any another approach to accomplish my task!
> - I just want to know - if it is possible to accomplish it in this approach or not?
> - I do have a jquery support in my chrome.extention
> - I am a Newbie **:** *Newbie, newb, noob, or n00b is a slang term for a novice or newcomer, or somebody inexperienced in any profession or activity.*
>
>   ### Wish you the best of everything!

Comment: BTW, sticking those URLs in every possible permission you can think of will not help solve the problem. It will just make your extension less secure and scare the user with its many permission requirements.

Comment: Thanks for your care and concern. As i have mentioned, i am a newbie and trying to figure out the problem. I am over exposed for the task on purpose to eliminate the security reasons for failing. After i will accomplish the task i am going to reduct the manifest.json in a very secure way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. What you need is [Message passing](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html), which will allow you to send messages between content scripts and your background page. If you handle the input inside your background page, you can send relevant data back to the appropriate tab.

Comment: Thanks for your time for answering my question. I am trying to workout my task with your sugestion. I will accept your answer as soon as i will accomplish my task with Message Passing. Best regards!